# How to display out of list items in a combobox?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a `tbl_ProjectList` that includes the project's *Name* and *End Date*.

- A `qry_cboProject` queries this table to only display projects in a combobox on `Subform A` where the *End Date* is after the selected date on `Subform B`, both on `Mainform C`.
- On `Subform A`, a macro copies (`INSERT INTO` SQL) projects from `Subform B's` previous months into the new months. However, if an out-of-date project gets copied over to a new month, the combobox field would be empty for that record, even though the *Key* exists on the back-end.

I've tried playing with the combobox's properties on `Subform A` by changing the `Bound Column`, `Column Count`, `Column Widths`, and `Limit To List`, but am only able to get the out-of-date project to display by its *Key*, rather than its *Name*.

The front-end reasoning for this macro is that employees do not have to repetitively select the same projects for each month, and employees already working on out-of-date projects may still need to put in some hours to close out the project.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please step back and provide pertinent details. What is the purpose of mainform and subforms? What is purpose of (bound or unbound?) comboboxes? Please post their SQL record sources? What is *Key*? What does *Out-of-Date* mean? Use Edit link to add this information and not in comments.

Comment: If combobox list is filtered then alias values are not available for display in record that has the data that is excluded from list. This is a well-known aspect of cascading (dependent) combobox used on continuous or datasheet form. You would have to dynamically modify the combobox RowSource to filter/not filter as needed. Only filter the list for NewRecord row so out-of-date projects cannot be selected. Or Don't copy out-of-date records. Or filter them from the form RecordSource.

Answer (score 1):

The order in which fields show up in you combo box depends on how the control source is querying the information i.e. to get name and not the key to show up in a combobox using the a control source query like the following:

```
SELECT Key, Name FROM tbl_ProjectList
```

You would need to set the following attributes:

```
Column Count: 2
Column Width: 0"; 2"
Bound Column: 1
```

It sounds like you may need to requery the control source as well. This should cause all the information to update.

Answer (score 1):

@Parfait - apologies for not describing my problem in more detail. There are multiple subforms on one main form to allow the user to select a date in one subform, which populates projects on a second subform and responsibilities on a third subform.

Jeffrey's suggestion made me realize that the underlying query to the combobox should be adjusted for projects that are carried over into new months, where a foreign key exists in the underlying `tbl_ProjectUserEntry`

Therefore, I added a `WHERE` criteria to the query, which uses a `DLookUp` function to see if the foreign key exists:

`DLookUp("[DateID]","tbl_ProjectUserEntry","[DateID] =" & Forms.frm_UserEntry.tbDateID) IS NOT NULL`

`frm_UserEntry` is the main form..

Again, apologies for my brief description to a complex problem.